# linq query to fetch employee name of those employee who is working on exactly 3 projects

Tags: c#, linq

i an having two tables as follows:

1)employee

2)project

employee table records:

```
empid       empname        project_id
1            abc             101

2            pqr             100

3            lmn             99

4            abc             99

5            abc             100
```

project table:

```
pid   pname

99    jknkj

100    nkj

101    kjkjn
```

now i want to fetch employee name of those employee who is working on exactly 3 project?

i want linq query.can anybody with me with linq query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and group your `Employees` based on `project_id` then get the groups that contains exactly `3` employees:

```
db.Employees.GroupBy(x => x.project_id)
.Where(x => x.Count() == 3)
.SelectMany(x => x.Select(e => e.empname));
```

Edit: the below comment is correct, you can group your records by `emp_name` in order the fix that issue:

```
db.Employees.GroupBy(x => x.empname)
.Where(x => x.Count() == 3)
.Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: This gets the projects that have 3 people working on them, not people that are working on 3 projects.

Comment: @juharr you are right.thanks for pointing it out, I updated my answer, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to fetch employees who are working on exactly 3 projects, do something like this:

```
var Counts =
        from e in employees
        group p by e.empname into g
        where g.Count == 3
        select new { Employee = g.Key, ProjectCount = g.Count() };
```

and if you want to want fetch project on which exactly 3 employees working then do like this:

```
var Counts =
            from e in employees
            group p by e.projectid into g
            where g.Count == 3
            select new { Porject= g.Key, EmployeeCount = g.Count() };
```